# Adding a new real-time shipping system to older X-Cart

Tags: x-cart, shipping-method

Trying to add a new real time shipping system to an existing, older (4.2.x) version of X-Cart and I can not figure out how to implement it properly.  Plan is to put the lookup into a new shipping/mod_*.php file and from what I can tell merge $intershipper_rates with the response I get from the rating API.  I just don't know how to reliably integrate it nor if I need to manually add anything into the database to make it work properly.  There doesn't seem to be any reference material or documentation for the older version I can easily access to figure it out, either.  If anybody can give me a hand wrapping my head around this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below replace the 'CPC' substring with your new shipper code.

---

1) Create functions like

- func_shipper_CPC
- func_get_package_limits_CPC
- func_check_limits_CPC

in a new file like 
shipping/mod_CPC.php

2) Change the array

```
$mods = array("USPS", "CPC", "ARB", "FEDEX");
```

in the shipping/myshipper.php

3) Add a row to the shipping options table

```
$params = func_query_first ("SELECT * FROM $sql_tbl[shipping_options] WHERE carrier='CPC'");
```

4) Add possible shipping methods in the xcart_shipping table

```
INSERT INTO xcart_shipping VALUES (null,'Canada Post Expedited','','L','CPC','81',20,'Y','CEX',0.00,0.00,1020,'','');
INSERT INTO xcart_shipping VALUES (null,'Canada Post Regular','','L','CPC','82',10,'Y','CRE',0.00,0.00,1010,'','');
INSERT INTO xcart_shipping VALUES (null,'Canada Post Xpresspost USA','','I','CPC','89',90,'Y','',0.00,0.00,2030,'','');
.....
```